# clearing array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I try `playerNameArray.length = 0;`  this doesn't empty the array, it makes those values be `undefined`.

I try `playerNameArray = [];` this doesn't empty the array, it makes those values be `undefined`.

I try `var playerNameArray = new Array ();`  this doesn't empty the array, it makes those values be `undefined`.

Maybe the problem is the initial array is public and i try to empty them inside of functions?

Maybe the problem is I need that array to be public in my JavaScript because on my html page I pass the array in a function and the page wont recognize the array if I initialize it inside the function I use it?

I add each array object to a database, but a user should be able to create a new array after inserting the first one.  I tried to cheese my insert statement and said if the array element != 'undefined' then insert it but it completely ignored that and inserted the `undefined`.

any suggestions please?

the code is as follows:

```
var createListCounter = 0;
var playerID = new Array();
var playerNameArray = new Array();

function addToList(espnPlayerID, playerName) {
    playerID[createListCounter] = espnPlayerID; playerNameArray[createListCounter]                =playerName;
    createListCounter++
    var url = "";
    $('#accumListPlayer').append('<tr><td>'+ playerName + '</td></tr>');
}
```

then on a button click i iterate through that array and save it t oa db.  once that completes, i need the array to have nothing in it.  if i still have the original objects in it, they write to the database again.

Comment: Can you show the code where you use the array please? If `playerNameArray = []` doesn't work, then you are in the wrong scope.

Comment: your array is clean.. the unexisting elements are always undefined http://jsfiddle.net/4tZga/

Comment: By clear do you mean the elements should be = ""

Comment: What is the difference between having variables undefined and clearing the array? If you cleared the array, everything inside it will be undefined since it hasn't been given a value, isn't that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting it equal to `[]` or `new Array()` overwrites the current value with a blank array.

If you are looping the array you can check if it has any elements by testing its length:

```
if(playerNameArray.length > 0) // has at least one element
```

You can also test individual elements of the array using the `typeof` function:

```
if(typeof(playerNameArray[3]) == 'undefined')
{
    // element 3 is undefined
}
```

Comment: both making it equal [] or making it a new array still leaves the old values as undefined

Comment: @Jon what do you want the old values to become? If you clear the array, they are gone, zilch, nada, none-existent. The array is now the same as when it was originally declared, with no elements whatsoever. They can't be anything else other than undefined. If you want to make them a blank string or some other value then that isn't clearing it.

Comment: thats exactly what i want, an blank, brand new array.  once i have those values in my database, i dont need them in the array.  i use the array to add them to the database.   so what your telling me is there is nothing better i can do than have the values as undefined?

Comment: @Jon, yes the best you can do is clear the array so that there are no elements. That shouldn't be a problem, because like in my answer, you can check if there are elements before trying to access them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.setAll = function(v) {
    var i, n = this.length;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        this[i] = v;
    }
};
```

and then you could actually do

```
playerNameArray.setAll("")
```

Comment: would that not then continue to add new elements and insert empty strings in the database where they were set?  ie, if i set elements 04- to "" the next element doesnt add at 0, it adds at 5